# Was it possible to complete the third rotation in Killer Gorilla?

Tags: bbc-micro

As a kid I played a lot of Killer Gorilla on the BBC micro. This game was a clone of Donkey Kong.

Like Donkey Kong it had four levels, which the game rotated through and on each rotation they got harder. I've found a few videos on Youtube, but I haven't found any that show the BBC micro version past the first rotation.

[Killer Gorilla - BBC Micro playthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9moA7SlTBaQ&pp=ygUka2lsbGVyIGdvcmlsbGEgYmJjIG1pY3JvIHBsYXl0aHJvdWdo) shows the first rotation on the BBC micro.

I recall getting through the first two rotations and on to the third level of the third rotation, but I recall that said level seemed impossibly difficult, everything was just moving way too fast.

Was I just unskilled or is said level basically a killscreen?

---

I did find some playthroughs of other versions that got further: [Killer Gorilla on the Acorn Electron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptjLXK7QFlg) is an Acorn Electron playthrough that reached the third rotation but died on the second level. I also found a amstrad CPC playthrough that made it through four rotations but that version did not exhibit the extreme speedup I remember from the BBC micro.

Comment: Did you try to use an emulator capable of slowing down?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Killer Gorilla](http://www.bbcmicro.co.uk/game.php?id=7), like many Beeb games, is really hard. It's notorious for fast and random events that will lose you a life even if you're on best form.

This playthrough appears to get further than you suggested: [Killer Gorilla Level 5 (Stardot Forums HSC, Season 16, Championship Round)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqLoMfMLQ90). It's from the [High Score Challenge Season 16 - Rd Champ - Killer Gorilla - stardot.org.uk](https://stardot.org.uk/forums/viewtopic.php?t=23674) forum thread. The seasoned players there suggest that lives can be lost unfairly.

Comment: This seems to answer the question that yes the third rotation is possible. The moving platforms don't seem as fast as I remember but it's possible my memory is faulty after so many years.

Comment: It can happen with personal memory. I thought that Chuckie Egg on the Amstrad CPC was "impossible" at the time, but there are playthroughs of it going much further